# ¿como puedo recorrer un objeto tipo json en js? y después como se asigna el contenido en una tabla?

Tags: javascript, json

```
   0
:
{Codigo_Detalle: "2", Codigo_Producto: "1", Cantidad: "5", Precio_Unitario: "800", pre_cant: "4000",…}

1
:
{Codigo_Detalle: "1", Codigo_Producto: "2", Cantidad: "2", Precio_Unitario: "500", pre_cant: "1000",…}
```

esto recibo en el obj

```
$("#agregar").on("click",function(){
  producto = $("#idventa").val();
  $.ajax({
         url: base_url + "notaCredito/agregar",
         type:"POST",
         dataType:"json",
         data:{'id': producto},
         success:function(data){
       alert(data)
        html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td><input type='hidden' name='idproductos[]' value='"+data[0].id+"'>"+data[0].CodigoVenta+"</td>";
        html += "<td>"+data[0].Nombre_Pro+"</td>";
        html += "<td><input type='hidden' name='precios[]' value='"+data[0].Precio_Unitario+"'>"+data[0].Precio_Unitario+"</td>";
        html += "<td><input type='text' name='cantidades[]' value='1' class='cantidades'></td>";
        html += "<td><input type='hidden' name='importes[]' value='"+data[0].Precio_Unitario+"'><p>"+data[0].Precio_Unitario+"</p></td>";
        html += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-remove-producto'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span></button></td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        $("#tbventas tbody").append(html);

        sumar();




            },
            error:function(){
              alert('error');
            }

         });


 });
```

anteriormente solo rescataba un solo dato como se muestra en el codigo..
pero ahora necesito recorrer la var data y cargar todo el contenido en la tabla y no se como hacerlo..

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Necesitas explicar mas tu problema, como por ejemplo a que tipo de tabla se va a asignar el contenido? a una de mysql o una tabla en html? también poner tu código que estas usando para ayudarte mas ;)

Comment: oka perdon , es mi primer post y ademas soy nobato aun, agregue mas informacion..

Answer (score 0):

Mucho mejor, mira aqui tienes un ejemplo usando un `forEach` de javascript puedes iterar sobre tu json donde `data` es el json completo y `element` es el elemento en iteración:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#agregar").on("click",function(){
    producto = $("#idventa").val();
    $.ajax({
         url: base_url + "notaCredito/agregar",
         type:"POST",
         dataType:"json",
         data:{'id': producto},
         success:function(data){
            data.forEach(element => {
                html = "<tr>";
                html += "<td><input type='hidden' name='idproductos[]' value='"+element.id+"'>"+element.CodigoVenta+"</td>";
                html += "<td>"+element.Nombre_Pro+"</td>";
                html += "<td><input type='hidden' name='precios[]' value='"+element.Precio_Unitario+"'>"+element.Precio_Unitario+"</td>";
                html += "<td><input type='text' name='cantidades[]' value='1' class='cantidades'></td>";
                html += "<td><input type='hidden' name='importes[]' value='"+element.Precio_Unitario+"'><p>"+element.Precio_Unitario+"</p></td>";
                html += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-remove-producto'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span></button></td>";
                html += "</tr>";

                $("#tbventas tbody").append(html);

                sumar();
            });
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
 });
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda, saludos!

Comment: :o No tenía idea de que pudieses utilizar forEcach así, me falta aprender aun mas. Buen dato. había buscado una solución fácil y eficaz

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias 

Comment: Gracias! puedes dar palomita verde!

Answer (score 0):

No se como viene estructurado tu json, pero vas a necesitar hacer un loop justo donde lo recibis para poder leer los objetos dentro del JSON, por ejemplo:

```
  $("#agregar").on("click",function(){
    producto = $("#idventa").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "notaCredito/agregar",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{'id': producto},
        success:function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ //Recorremos los indices
                var obj = data[i]; //obtenemos cada objeto del json
                for (var llave in obj){ //recorremos los valores del objeto
                    var valor = obj[llave]; //Obtenemos el valor de cada key
                    //Aqui es donde armas tu tabla
                    document.write("<br> - " + llave + ": " + valor);
                }
            }    
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```